Why is "were spilled" wrong in this sentence?
I asked a question on this site and in one of the comments someone pointed out something grammatically wrong with this sentence that I had used in the Body:

Traffic became increasingly congested as more and more vehicles were spilled onto the highway by the various rural roads that (joined into/merged into/connected into/ended in/intersected with???) the highway.

Ignore the bracketed part, that was part of the question. Mistake pointed out was regarding the use of 'were' before 'spilled'. Correct use according to that user was:

Traffic became increasingly congested as more and more vehicles spilled onto the highway by the various rural roads that ended at the highway.

Now, this sentence is also proper to express the same meaning.(if you replace 'by' with 'from')
However, what is wrong with the original sentence? As I understand it, original is simply the passive form of

Traffic became increasingly congested as various rural roads that joined into the highway spilled more and more vehicles onto the highway.


You might want to edit the title of this question. "Proofreading" questions, asking to find mistakes in a passage without a clear area of concern, are off-topic. This question does have a clear area of concern; maybe give it a title something like "Is passive voice ungrammatical in 'vehicles were spilled by roads'"? Looks like Fattie deleted their original comment so I'm not sure what objection there was, but this seems to be writing advice rather than grammatical objection. The active voice is just simpler and smoother here, but it's grammatical.

You are correct. #1 and #3 are correct. #2 is incorrect.

First, note that the verb spill is used intransitively in your sentence, and therefore it cannot be passivized. The subject NP is more and more vehicles. The various rural roads is not the agent of spill, but a PP functioning as an adverb of space modifying the verb spill.
Here is the definition from the OED that corresponds to this intransitive use:

intransitive. To flow or run over the brim or side; to escape or be wasted in this manner. Frequently with prepositions and adverbs. Also figurative.

The metropolitan area of New York City has spilled [not has been spilled] into the surrounding countryside, engulfing cities and communities which had their own economic and cultural centers.


This example provided by Cambridge is similar:

Crowds of fans spilled [not were spilled] onto the field at the end of the game.

You can say that milk is spilled by someone, but you cannot say that vehicles or crowds are spilled by an agent.

I could not find an specific example to mention here, but have read in novels, on multiple occasions, usage of phrases like 'trail spat him into the clearing', 'alley spat him onto the footpath', in which trails, alleys, roads etc. are treated as agents. Are these usages wrong? Can a road or a trail be an agent? (Note: Many of these novels are not proofread.)

I guess metaphorically you could do that, but it is not so idiomatic as the intransitive use.

You can sometimes force metaphors but this one would be a real stretch. Check this Ngram: No instance for passive use.

It's unusual, but hardly ungrammatical. I've found 'All the dirt roads spewed cars and pickups and farm trucks on to [some highway?]' [Black Sunshine; Ninie Hammon]. The first suggested correction OP reports is however ungrammatical (the [non-sentient–] agentive by-phrase is unacceptable).

This is just wrong; it’s fine to have a non-sentient agent in a passive voice construction.

@EdwinAshworth You may be right about spewed but this verb cannot be used intransitively in the same way as spill to serve this metaphor.

'Spill' obviously has a transitive usage; metaphorical broadening to volitionalise [see here], or perhaps rather animate, the non-sentient agent is not a vast leap.
